# IN (Select ...) performance much worse than IN (values) in specific databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

I find a huge difference in performance when I run two equivalent queries, one with `IN (<values>)` and the other one with `IN (SELECT <same values>)`.
As I managed to reproduce this problem in several versions of MS SQL Server, including...

- Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-GDR) (KB4583463) - 12.0.6164.21 (X64)
  Nov  1 2020 04:25:14   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard
  Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU23) (KB5000685) - 14.0.3381.3 (X64)
  Feb  9 2021 12:08:50   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 
  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU10)
  (KB5001090) - 15.0.4123.1 (X64)   Mar 22 2021 18:10:24   Copyright
  (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows
  Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

...I found this does not depend on the SQL Server version, and does not depend on the specific database, but on the specific database server instance. I mean: if I find this performance issue in some database, I am able to reproduce it in every database in that same database instance.

That makes me think there is some sort of setting/configuration that would allow me to get the same (good) performance in the databases where this IN (SELECT...) runs so slow. This problem is producing several deadlocks and timeouts in some of our databases.

**Script to reproduce the problem** (again, being able to reproduce it depends on some setting that I don't know but I want to find):

I create a test table with the following script:
It inserts 10.000.000 "Penguins", and they are linked in couples (i.e: 5.000.000 couples of Penguins)

```
--Create test table
    CREATE TABLE Penguins
    (
    Id INT NOT NULL Primary Key,
    PartnerId INT NOT NULL
    );

--Create index
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Penguins_PartnerId] ON [Penguins]
    (
        [PartnerId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON);


--Insert 10,000,000 test rows
    WITH x AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) v(n))
    INSERT INTO Penguins(Id, PartnerId)
    SELECT internal.Number, CASE When internal.Number % 2 = 0 THEN internal.Number + 1 ELSE internal.Number - 1 END
    FROM
        (SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n + 10000*tensthousands.n + 100000*hundredthousands.n + 1000000*millions.n Number
        FROM x ones,     x tens,      x hundreds,       x thousands,       x tensthousands,       x hundredthousands,       x millions
        ) internal
    ORDER BY 1
```

Then I run this query, which in some databases takes 12 seconds:
I want to see the data of 3 specific penguins (4540734, 4540736, 6394285) and their partners:

```
--Run query
    declare @p0 as Table (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    )
    INSERT INTO @p0 (ID) VALUES (4540734)
    INSERT INTO @p0 (ID) VALUES (4540736)
     
     
    SELECT *
    FROM Penguins
    INNER JOIN Penguins Partner ON Partner.Id  = Penguins.PartnerId
     
    WHERE
        Penguins.Id IN (
            SELECT Id FROM @p0
        )
        Or
        Penguins.Id = 6394285
```

But in those same databases, if instead of using a `SELECT ...` I specify the list of values, I get the same results but the query takes less than 1 second:

```
--Run query  
    SELECT *
    FROM Penguins
    INNER JOIN Penguins Partner ON Partner.Id  = Penguins.PartnerId
     
    WHERE
        Penguins.Id IN (
            --By defining the values as a list, it runs in less than 1 second
            4540734,4540736
        )
        Or
        Penguins.Id = 6394285
```

Bear in mind that I get this difference only if I combine the "IN (SELECT...)" with the "OR Penguins.Id = 6394285"

Execution plan of slow execution of `IN (SELECT ...` in the servers where it runs slow:

[image: Execution plan of slow execution SELECT]

Execution plan of fast execution of `IN (SELECT ...` in the servers where it runs fast:
[image: Execution plan of fast execution SELECT]

Execution plan of fast execution, using `IN (values)`:

[image: Execution plan of fast execution]

This question is not about how to modify the query to improve its performance, but to identify why the execution plan is so different in different database server instances.

Could you please help me identify what this performance difference depends on? This behaviour surprised many experienced database developers I talked with.
Thank you.

Comment: just out of interest, what if `p0` is a temp table rather than a table variable?

Comment: Please share the full query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan also what happens if you try `WHERE Penguins.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @p0 UNION SELECT 6394285)`

Comment: @AakashM changing `p0` into a temp table does not change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: @Charlieface , I will try that so I can give you an answer, but as I said my question is not about making changes in the query to make it run fast, but to understand why it runs so slow in some specific database instances. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like it's because of that `OR`, which is forcing a nested loops with the table variable on the wrong side, and also the fact that it's a complete unknown as to how many row are going to match

Comment: @Charlieface but I don't see why in most of my database server instances this is not a problem and both queries run in less than 1 second. Thank you

Comment: Probably to do with things like statistics which may be slightly different on each server. Best is to write a query that *always* gets the right plan, rather than write a bad query which you need to mess about with indexing and stuff to get it to work. Please share the query plans if you want better advice than that